# How to store data from ELKI gui?

Tags: java, user-interface, elki

I am struggling to Output the resulting clusters to a .txt or .csv File. Is there a way to write a .csv  file like: lon;lat;ClusterId From ELKI GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the resulthandler parameter.

There is a result writer that produces CSV files.